# refresh rate for insert/update for subscriptions? rate,quantity, etc

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I have questions related pushing messages to a user.

Here is the use-case.

A user is walking inside a wifi enabled warehouse and we would like to use the glasses to send critical information and warnings about the components in that building which required the user to interact with the component(s).

We have used push notifications in android devices with ok results, but with a live hud I would like faster updates.

Basically we will send something like this to the user

```
 {
"html": "<article>\n  <section>\n    <strong class=\"red\">ALERT </strong>13:10  device            ABCD tolerance failure. \n    </p>\n  </section>\n</article>\n",
 "notification": {
"level": "DEFAULT"
 } 
}
```

1. How quickly can we get the information to the device?
2. What is the update rate?  If we see an alert from a machine can, how quickly can we refresh the user of its status.
3. Is there some type of flood protection that would cause us grief?
4. I assume native api will have more options, such as polling or some type of custom subscription service which we could use for faster updates than google's service. Is this correct?

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 2):

This is not something that is expected to be done with the Mirror API.  The GDK is where you would want to do this and they are taking feature requests.  You might want to add your use case to this thread:

https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=75

To answer some of your other questions:

1 - Mirror API card pushes happen within seconds

2 - Seconds

3 - You are currently limited to 1000 card pushes a day per developer account, so that would be shared across all your users

4 - Curently there is no supported way to do that

As a final thought, if you really want to do this without official support, you could watch this video which shows you how to run "normal" android apk's on Glass.  It is a presentation from Google I/O 2013:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPethpwuYEk

Comment: Great answer Mark! One clarification: projects will not be limited to 1000 QPD forever. We'll be granting more quota to projects soon.

Comment: I'm disappointed in right now with google's options.  Due to information sensitivity I believe I will not be able to push the data through google and it must stay in the intranet.  I was thinking about a custom polling service as worst case solution, but  I dont want to push a solution to a client that is not viable or requires an unsupported hacking.  I hope someone from google can explain why we they do not support subscriptions or polling outside of googles service.  Is there a plan to support this in the future?

Comment: Relating to topic 4, why isn't that feature (polling/subscription) currently supported?